# What a Table Class really does in Joomla! MVC structure?

Tags: class, components, joomla2.5

I'm new to programming Joomla components so will be very glad if someone describe (if possible with an example) the functionality of a table class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XML form (typically located in models/forms). You choose to have the same names as those in your database as those field names but actually it isn't compulsory.

Table class always extends `JTable` and api refernce link is [JTable](https://api.joomla.org/cms-2.5/classes/JTable.html).
You go through a 3 stage process.

`bind` takes the array of data that comes from your form and then stores any data from it into the table class.

`check` Method to perform sanity checks on the JTable instance properties to ensure they are safe to store in the database.

`store` then stores the binded data into the database table.

For example we need to some fields of form to database

```
public function bind($src, $ignore = array())
{
    foreach ($src as $field => $value)
    {
        $this->$field = $value;
    }
    return parent::bind($src, $ignore);
}
```

It will attempt to match $field to a database column storing the value if it exists.